# How to stage a rename without subsequent edits in git?

Tags: git, file-rename, git-add

I have a file that I've renamed and then edited. I would like to tell Git to stage the rename, but not the content modifications. That is, I wish to stage the deletion of the old file name, and the addition of the old file contents with the new file name.

So I have this:

```
Changes not staged for commit:

        deleted:    old-name.txt

Untracked files:

        new-name.txt
```

but want either this:

```
Changes to be committed:

        new file:   new-name.txt
        deleted:    old-name.txt

Changes not staged for commit:

        modified:   new-name.txt
```

or this:

```
Changes to be committed:

        renamed:    old-name.txt -> new-name.txt

Changes not staged for commit:

        modified:   new-name.txt
```

(where the similarity measure should be 100%).

I can't think of a straightforward way to do this.

Is there syntax for getting the contents of a specific revision of a specific file, and adding this to the git staging area under a specified path?

The delete part, with `git rm`, is fine:

```
$ git rm old-name.txt
```

It's the add part of the rename I'm struggling with. (I could save the new contents, checkout a fresh copy (for the old contents), `mv` in the shell, `git add`, and then recover the new contents, but that seems like a very long way around!)

Thanks!

Comment: `git mv` alone won't work if the original file is already deleted, or the destination path exists. You need to do the save/restore process that you outlined... during which, you can use `git mv` instead of `mv + git add`. Since git wasn't tracking `new-name.txt` when you made changes to it, as-is it can't help separate those changes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Git doesn't really do renames.  They're *all* computed in an "after the fact" fashion: git compares one commit with another and, *at compare time*, decides if there was a rename.  This means that whether git considers something "a rename" changes dynamically.  I know you're asking about a commit you haven't even made yet, but bear with me, this really all does tie in (but the answer will be long).

---

When you ask git (via `git show` or `git log -p` or `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`) "what happened in the last commit", it runs a diff of the previous commit (`HEAD^` or `HEAD~1` or the actual raw SHA-1 for the previous commit—any of these will do to identify it) and the current commit (`HEAD`).  In making that diff it may discover that there used to be an `old.txt` and isn't any more; and there was no `new.txt` but there is now.

These file names—files that used to be there but aren't, and files that are there now that weren't—are put into pile marked "candidates for rename".  Then, for each name in the pile, git compares "old contents" and "new contents".  The comparison for *exact match* is super-easy because of the way git reduces contents to SHA-1s; if the exact-match fails, git switches to an optional "are the contents at least similar" diff to check for renames.  With `git diff` this optional step is controlled by the `-M` flag.  With other commands it's either set by your `git config` values, or hardcoded into the command.

Now, back to the staging area and `git status`: what git stores in the index / staging-area is basically "a prototype for the next commit".  When you `git add` something, git stores the file contents right at that point, computing the SHA-1 in the process and then storing the SHA-1 in the index.  When you `git rm` something, git stores a note in the index saying "this path name is being deliberately removed on the next commit".

The `git status` command, then, simply does a diff—or really, two diffs: `HEAD` vs index, for what is going to be committed; and index vs work-tree, for what *could* be (but isn't yet) going to be committed.

In that first diff, git uses the same mechanism as always to detect renames.  If there's a path in the `HEAD` commit that is gone in the index, and a path in the index that's new and not in the `HEAD` commit, it's a candidate for rename-detection.  The `git status` command hardwires rename detection to "on" (and the file count limit to 200; with just one candidate for rename detection this limit is plenty).

---

What does all this mean for your case?  Well, you renamed a file (without using `git mv`, but it doesn't really matter because `git status` finds the rename, or fails to find it, at `git status` time), and now have a newer, different version of the new file.

If you `git add` the new version, that newer version goes into the repo, and its SHA-1 is in the index, and when `git status` does a diff it will compare the new and old.  If they're at least "50% similar" (the hardwired value for `git status`), git will tell you the file is renamed.

Of course, `git add`-ing the *modified* contents is not quite what you asked for: you wanted to do an intermediate commit where the file is *only* renamed, i.e., a commit with a tree with the new name, but the old contents.

You don't *have* to do this, because of all of the above dynamic rename detection.  If you *want* to do it (for whatever reason) ... well, git doesn't make it all that easy.

The most straightforward way is just as you suggest: move the modified contents somewhere out of the way, use `git checkout -- old-name.txt`, then `git mv old-name.txt new-name.txt`, then commit.  The `git mv` will both rename the file in the index/staging-area, and rename the work-tree version.

If `git mv` had a `--cached` option like `git rm` does, you could just `git mv --cached old-name.txt new-name.txt` and then `git commit`.  The first step would rename the file in the index, without touching the work-tree.  But it doesn't: it insists on overwriting the work-tree version, and it insists that the old name must exist in the work-tree to start.

The single step method for doing this without touching the work-tree is to use `git update-index --index-info`, but that, too, is somewhat messy (I'll show it in a moment anyway).  Fortunately, there's one last thing we can do.  I've set up the same situation you had, by renaming the old name to the new one and modifying the file:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    old-name.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    new-name.txt
```

What we do now is, **first, manually put the file back under its old name, then use `git mv` to switch again to the new name**:

```
$ mv new-name.txt old-name.txt
$ git mv old-name.txt new-name.txt
```

This time `git mv` updates the name in the index, but *keeps the original contents* as the index SHA-1, yet *moves the work-tree version* (new contents) into place in the work-tree:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    old-name.txt -> new-name.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   new-name.txt
```

Now just `git commit` to make a commit with the rename in place, but not the new contents.

(Note that this depends on there not being a new file with the old name!)

---

What about using `git update-index`?  Well, first let's get things back to the "changed in work-tree, index matches HEAD commit" state:

```
$ git reset --mixed HEAD  # set index=HEAD, leave work-tree alone
```

Now let's see what's in the index for `old-name.txt`:

```
$ git ls-files --stage -- old-name.txt
100644 2b27f2df63a3419da26984b5f7bafa29bdf5b3e3 0   old-name.txt
```

So, what we need `git update-index --index-info` to do is to wipe out the entry for `old-name.txt` but make an otherwise identical entry for `new-name.txt`:

```
$ (git ls-files --stage -- old-name.txt;
   git ls-files --stage -- old-name.txt) |
  sed -e \
'1s/^[0-9]* [0-9a-f]*/000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/' \
      -e '2s/old-name.txt$/new-name.txt/' | 
  git update-index --index-info
```

(note: I broke the above up for posting purposes, it was all one line when I typed it in; in sh/bash, it should work broken-up like this, given the backslashes I added to continue the "sed" command).

There are some other ways to do this, but simply extracting the index entry twice and modifying the first one into a removal and the second with the new name seemed the easiest here, hence the `sed` command.  The first substitution changes the file mode (100644 but any mode would be turned into all-zeros) and SHA-1 (match any SHA-1, replace with git's special all-zeros SHA-1), and the second leaves the mode and SHA-1 alone while replacing the name.

When the update-index finishes, the index has recorded the removal of the old path and the addition of the new path (with same mode and SHA-1 as were in the old path).

Note that this could fail badly if the index had unmerged entries for `old-name.txt` since there might be other stages (1 to 3) for the file.

Comment: My favorite option of yours listed is to rename back to old, then use `git mv`.

Comment: Also, it may be worth noting that you could do `git stash` to get back to the original state, then perform the `git mv` for the rename.  After committing, you can use `git stash --pop`, with a possible merge conflict, to go back to where you were.

Comment: @BrianJ: yes, that (mv, then git mv) is definitely the easiest here.  It can be more difficult if you've made a new file with the old name, since there's no "free slot" for moving the 15-puzzle-pieces around in that case :-)

Comment: I don't think git would even see a rename at that point, would it?  If there was a new file with the old name?

Comment: @BrianJ: normally it wouldn't, and I think currently even with `--find-copies-harder` it doesn't now, but in the computationally-expensive mode it *could*, and perhaps someone might someday make git do that.  The fact that "git diff" can get smarter tomorrow is one of the arguments Linus uses for doing everything this way today.

Comment: `git diff` should be able to cope with this scenario, showing a rename from `A` to `B` and a new file at `A`, when the `-B` command line option is specified to enabling breaking of rewritten files (meaning that heavily modified files can be candidates for rename detection).  However `git status` does not enable this particular option directly.

Comment: @torek: wow! thank you for the very full, clear, and detailed answer. I'm sure that will be as helpful to others as much as it has been to me. You've come up with quite a few things to try. I will experiment…

Answer (score 27):

@torek gave a very clear and full answer. There's lots of very useful detail there; it's well worth a proper read.

But, for the sake of those in a rush, the crux of the very simple solution given was this:

> What we do now is, first, manually put the file back under its old
>   name, then use git mv to switch again to the new name:
>
> ```
> $ mv new-name.txt old-name.txt
> $ git mv old-name.txt new-name.txt
> ```

(It was just the `mv` back that I was missing, to make the `git mv` possible.)

Please upvote **@torek's** answer if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Git GUI Sourcetree. It has functionality for staging and unstaging "hunks" of a file or highlighting individual lines and staging or unstaging them.

I was able to stage the deleted file and new file to have the GUI detect it as a "rename". Then I went through and highlighted all the changed lines and unstaged them. So now I have the rename staged but none of the file changes.

I know not everyone uses this UI. But as far as I can tell it is based on the interactive staging of "patches" described here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging . So I'd look into that. Stage everything then un-stage patches.