# Selectively stage file modifications after rename

Tags: git

Quite often when using Git, I will rename a file and then modify it:

```
# Create file and commit
echo 1 > foo
git add .
git commit -m "A"

# Later, rename it
mv foo bar

# Later, modify it    
echo 2 >> bar
```

Afterwards, I want to:

- stage the rename of the file
- selectively stage modifications to the renamed file

However, `git add --patch` does not provide this option. It only prompts the user to stage the deletion of `foo` (old filename), and the addition of `bar` (new filename).

Is there a command I can use to only stage the rename, so I can then use `git add --patch` to stage modifications separately?

---

Note: I understand `git mv` provides some help here, as it renames the file and immediately stages the deletion/addition, so future interactive `git add`s will only include modification diffs. However, that's not always practical—sometimes renames happen outside of my control, such as when using an IDE.

Comment: I think you are thinking of `git add -p` rather than `git add --interactive`, although you can invoke the patch-add mode from the interactive mode.

Comment: @torek Thanks, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a command I can use to only stage the rename, so I can then use `git add --interactive` to stage modifications separately?

There is no nice user oriented command, which Git calls *porcelain* commands, for this.  (Mercurial has one—`hg mv --after`—and it would not be unreasonable to lobby for an `--after` option in `git mv`, to give you that.)  There is a *plumbing* command you can use, though; in fact, you can implement your own `git mv-after` using this, and I have done so.

#### Background

First, we should mention Git's *index*.  Git, like any commit-oriented version control system, has both a *current commit*, which Git calls `HEAD`, and a *work-tree*, which is where you have your files in their ordinary, non-version-controlled form so that all your normal non-version-control software can use them.  But Git introduces an intermediate step, called the *index* or *staging area*.  The short description of the index is that it is *where you build the next commit*.

When it comes to renaming files, there are a couple of intertwined issues here.  The first is that Git does not actually track renames at all.  Instead, it *reconstructs* (i.e., guesses-at) renames *at the time you request a diff*, including the `git show`, `git log -p`, and even `git status` commands.  This means that what you need to do is tell Git to *remove* the existing index entry for the old path name, and add a *new* index entry for the new path name.

Second, while there's a porcelain command to *remove* an index entry without touching the work-tree, the porcelain command to *add* an index entry is the *same* as the porcelain command to *update an existing* index entry.  Specifically:

```
git rm --cached path/to/file.ext
```

removes the index entry without touching the work-tree at all, and hence can remove an index entry that no longer has a corresponding work-tree file.  But:

```
git add path/to/newname.ext
```

not only *creates* an index entry for the new file, it does so by *copying the current contents* of the file into the index.  (This is slightly misleading, as we will see in a moment, but it *is* the problem.)  So if the file has been both renamed *and* modified by some GUI or IDE or other non-Git program, and you use both Git commands, this removes the old index entry just fine, but it writes the *new* data for the file under its new name, rather than copying the old data from the old index entry.

If only we had `git mv --after`, we might use it like this:

```
$ git status
$ program-that-renames-file-and-modifies-it
$ git status --short
 D name.ext
?? newname.ext
$ git mv --after name.ext newname.ext
```

to tell Git "take the index entry for `name.ext` and start calling it `newname.ext` instead".  But we don't, and this fails:

```
$ git mv name.ext newname.ext
fatal: bad source, source=name.ext, destination=newname.ext
```

There is a simple but clunky workaround:

1. Extract the old file from the index, under its old name, as its old version.
2. Move the new file out of the way.
3. Use `git mv` to update the index.
4. Move the new file back into place.

Hence:

```
$ git checkout -- name.ext && \
  mv newname.ext temp-save-it && \
  git mv name.ext newname.ext && \
  mv temp-save-it newname.ext
```

does the trick, but we must invent a temporary name (`temp-save-it`) and guarantee that it's unique.

#### Implementing `git mv-after`

If we run `git ls-files --stage`, we see *exactly what's in the index*:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 038d718da6a1ebbc6a7780a96ed75a70cc2ad6e2 0   README
100644 77df059b7ea5adaf8c7e238fe2a9ce8b18b9a6a6 0   name.ext
```

What the index stores is not actually the file's *content*, but rather the *hash ID* of one particular version of the file in the repository.  (Also, between the stage number `0` and the path name is a literal ASCII TAB character, character-code 9; this matters.)

All we need to do is add a new index entry that has the same *mode and hash ID* (and stage number 0) under the new name, while removing the old index entry.  There is a plumbing command to do just this, `git update-index`.  With the `--index-info`, the command reads its standard input, which should be formatted exactly the same way `git ls-files --stage` writes it.

The script to do this is a bit long, so I have it below *and* [in my "published scripts" repository now](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-mv-after).  But here it is in action:

```
$ git mv-after name.ext newname.ext
$ git status --short
RM name.ext -> newname.ext
```

The script could probably use a bit more work—for instance, a control-A in the file name will confuse the final `sed`—but it does function.  Place the script somewhere in your path (in my case, it is in my `~/scripts/` directory), name it `git-mv-after`, and invoke it as `git mv-after`.

---

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# mv-after: script to rename a file in the index

. git-sh-setup # for die() etc

TAB=$'\t'

# should probably use OPTIONS_SPEC, but not yet
usage()
{
    echo "usage: git mv-after oldname newname"
    echo "${TAB}oldname must exist in the index; newname must not"
}

case $# in
2) ;;
*) usage 1>&2; exit 1;;
esac

# git ls-files --stage does not test whether the entry is actually
# in the index; it exits with status 0 even if not.  But it outputs
# nothing so we can test that.
#
# We do, however, want to make sure that the file is at stage zero
# (only).
getindex()
{
    local output extra

    output="$(git ls-files --stage -- "$1")"
    [ -z "$output" ] && return 1
    extra="$(echo "$output" | sed 1d)"
    [ -z "$extra" ] || return 1
    set -- $output
    [ $3 == 0 ] || return 1
    printf '%s\n' "$output"
}

# check mode of index entry ($1) against arguments $2...$n
# return true if it matches one of them
check_mode()
{
    local i mode=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/ .*//')

    shift
    for i do
        [ "$mode" = "$i" ] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# make sure first entry exists
entry="$(getindex "$1")" || die "fatal: cannot find $1"
# make sure second entry does not
getindex "$2" >/dev/null && die "fatal: $2 already in index"

# make sure the mode is 100644 or 100755, it's not clear
# whether this works for anything else and it's clearly
# a bad idea to shuffle a gitlink this way.
check_mode "$entry" 100644 100755 || die "fatal: $1 is not a regular file"

# use git update-index to change the name.  Replace the first
# copy's mode with 0, and the second copy's name with the new name.
# XXX we can't use / as the delimiter in the 2nd sed; use $'\1' as
# an unlikely character
CTLA=$'\1'
printf '%s\n%s\n' "$entry" "$entry" |
    sed -e "1s/100[67][45][45]/000000/" -e "2s$CTLA$TAB.*$CTLA$TAB$2$CTLA" |
    git update-index --index-info
```

Comment: very interesting. +1. Parts of this answer remind me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29707465/6309

Comment: @VonC: yeah, I decided I should finally write it up as a script. :-)

Comment: BTW I note now another bug in the script: it checks (with `getindex`) that the new name does not exist in the index ... but it checks only stage 0. The `getindex` function is too clever here. If you are in the middle of a conflicted merge, and the new name exists in stages 1, 2, and/or 3, the script will clobber it. I'll probably fancy up `getindex` a bit at some point. It's good enough for now though.