# How to split a file rename and file change into two commits in Git?

Tags: git, git-commit

What I'm trying to do is split up both changes into two separated commits.
For example I got a file foo.txt with the following content:

```
foo.txt

1 foo
```

now the *filename* **and** *content* was changed to the following:

```
bar.txt

1 foo
```

I managed to let git recognize the filename change and stage it (with *git rm* and *git add*), this is what git shows me with

> git status
>
> renamed:    foo.txt -> bar.txt

How can I continue to get two commits, one with the filename change and one with the content change?

Comment: This is a very nice answer that describes in details what to do to seperate renaming from editing in the commits:
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707465/1988355

Comment: Thanks, I saw that solution but misunderstood. Further investigation has led to success! Thank you very much!